# How to find DISTINCT Combinations?

Tags: mysql, database

There are 3 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
  EID mediumint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  EName varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  EPincode mediumint unsigned NULL
);
```

EID is the Employee-Id of each Employee which is unique;

```
CREATE TABLE Project(
  PID mediumint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PName varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  MID mediumint UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (MID) REFERENCES Employee(EID)
);
```

MID is the Manager-Id of an Employee who is heading the Project.

```
CREATE TABLE Works_On(
  EID mediumint NOT NULL,
  PID mediumint NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (EID) REFERENCES Employee(EID),
  FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES Project(PID)
);
```

This table consist of all the Employees and Their Associated Project.

> An Employee can work on multiple Projects. A Project can be done by
>   multiple Employees. Each Project has a Manager. A Manager can have one
>   or more employees under him.

*I want to find a table consisting of Employee Name, Project Name and Manager Name. Please help.*

This is the query I have written so far but its not working :

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.EName AS "Employee Name"
               ,A.PName AS "Project Name"
               ,B.EName AS "Manager Name" 
FROM (SELECT P.PName
            ,E.EName 
      from Works_On W 
      NATURAL JOIN Project P 
      NATURAL JOIN Employee E) A,
(SELECT E.EName 
 from Project P 
 INNER JOIN Employee E ON P.MID = E.EID) B
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: where is the Manager name field?

Comment: Added the query I tried query in the question.

Comment: **Manager Name**  can be retrieved from the Employee Table

Comment: Pro tip: avoid `NATURAL JOIN`. This is confusing and not standard. Use standard explicit syntax for all your join : `LEFT/INNER JOIN...ON`

Comment: Thanks Thomas ! Will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select A.Employee_name,
       A.project_name,
       B.manager_name  from
      (
        SELECT
        P.PName AS project_name,
        E.EName AS Employee_name,
        E.EID,P.PID
        FROM Works_On W
        INNER JOIN Project P ON W.PID = P.PID
        INNER JOIN Employee E ON W.EID = E.EID

        ) as A           

       left join
       (

        SELECT
        E.EName AS manager_name,
        E.EID,P.PID
        FROM Project P
        INNER JOIN Employee E ON P.MID = E.EID

        ) B on A.PID=B.PID
```

Comment: {
    **"error"**: {
       **"code"**: "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
        **"errno"**: 1054,
        **"sqlMessage"**: "Unknown column 'E.EID' in 'on clause'",
        **"sqlState"**: "42S22"
    }
}

Comment: @AniketKumar i edited there was a slight column name missing in join query

Comment: No. of Rows returned is correct but Manager Name is not correct, some of the rows even returned null.

Comment: can you please share the data set of 3tables , it will help to find the problem

Comment: I have generated that dynamically over filldb.info

Comment: can you please share with me that generated dataset where query returned wrong result

Comment: [Dataset](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TRYg50kupxu1znVgIsfGCZWReYBaascEBKAIV_gp92g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @AniketKumar i edited my answer hope it will return all manager name properly

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT P.PName AS ProjectName,
       M.EName AS ManagerName, 
       E.EName AS EmployeeName 
FROM Project P 
     LEFT JOIN Employee M ON (P.MID=M.EID) 
     LEFT JOIN Works_On WO on (P.PID=WO.PID) 
     LEFT JOIN Employee E on (E.EID=WO.EID);
```

It worked.

Comment: hahahah you said it worked and got your answer as a result :)

Comment: LOL, I found the answer before you did. Still I am grateful to you for the help

Comment: Appreciate him from you got help by the way as you delayed to provide sample data thats why answered was late ans thanks for accepting

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT
    E.EName,
    P.PName,
    M.EName
FROM Employee E 
    INNER JOIN Employee M ON M.EID = E.EID
    INNER JOIN Project P ON E.EID = P.MID
    INNER JOIN Works_On W ON W.EID = E.EID AND W.PID = P.PID
```

This might help you.

Comment: That didn't worked. Wrong Output. Only EName and PName columns are there on the result. When I made aliases all the 3 columns are visible, though.